# MDX query - limiting the result through a range constraint

Tags: mdx, saiku

This is a MDX query generated through [Saiku Analytics](http://www.meteorite.bi/products/saiku). I'd like to limit the list to have only those with [Is Applied] > 10. Please let me know how I can accomplish this.

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Applicant Usage].[Geo].[Citizenship Country].Members}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Is Applied]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [Application Fact]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is the usual way to accomplish this in mdx:

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
  FILTER(
    {[Applicant Usage].[Geo].[Citizenship Country].Members}
    ,[Measures].[Is Applied] > 10
  )
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Is Applied]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [Application Fact]
```

This is the documentation for the SSAS implementation of filter:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx